# How to create custom shadow for view?

Tags: java, android, xml, styles, shadow

I wanna to create custom shadow for view which i customize as like as my plan.

Custom Shadow looks like Card View elevation.
[image]

I need this type of shadow

Comment: Min sdk version?

Comment: minSdkVersion 21

Comment: Try to use `ShapeDrawable` : https://medium.com/@ArmanSo/take-control-of-views-shadow-android-c6b35ba573e9

Answer (score 0):

Hm. This one is extremely simple and producing very similar (imo) result to what you requested. Obviously params like elevation, corner radius etc can/should be tweaked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/textview_first"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I said that, i need Shadow which **looks like** CardElevation without using of cardview or card elevation or elevation. because i know i cannot change color of elevation.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one. This works for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Bottom 2dp Shadow -->
<item>
    <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#d8d8d8" />
        <corners android:radius="7dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- White Top color -->
<item android:bottom="3px">
    <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <corners android:radius="7dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Thanks but its not right answer of my question. it seems like bottom stroke not shadow..